# HTML Form element to URL

Tags: html, forms, url, post, get

I am using an eCommerce engine script that uses a different search method.

Instead of a URL using GET like this:

```
http://search.com/searchc?q=the+query
```

It uses

```
http://search.com/searchc/the+query
```

How can I make a form to POST or GET to that, because this form makes the URL

```
http://search.com/searchc/?q=the+query


<form action="/searchc/" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Also tried this (get or post do not work for both of these)

```
<form action="/searchc/" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="" name="">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reliable way has two components: Client-side JavaScript manipulation, which turns form submission to a request as needed, and (as backup for non-JS situations) a simple server-side redirect utility which receives a request from the form and redirects it as modified.

Something like this (for the GET case):

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/redirect"
  onsubmit="location.href = document.getElementById('f1').value + 
  document.getElementById('q').value; return false">
<input type="text" id="q" name="f2">
<input type="submit" value="go">
<input type=hidden id=f1 name=f1 value="http://search.com/search/">
</form>
```

Here http://www.example.com/redirect is some server-side form handler that just reads the form fields and picks up fields named f1, f2,..., concatenates them into a single string, and redirects using it as a URL. As a CGI script, this would be

```
use CGI qw(:standard);
$dest = '';
$i = 1;
while(param('f'.$i)) {
   $dest .= param('f'.$i++); }
print "Location: $dest\n\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="/searchc/" method="post" onsubmit="this.action+=this.q.value;return true">
   <input type="text" id="q">
   <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

spaces will be submited as %20

you can use

```
this.action+=this.q.value.split(' ').join('+')
```

to replace them

Answer (score 0):

This is very strange url pattern, but anyway you could do something like:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var url = '/searchc/' + encodeURIComponent($(this).find('[name=q]').val());
        window.location = url;
        return false;
    });    
});
```